# Trait bound i8: From<u8> was not satisfied

Tags: rust

For the sake of the argument, let's say I want to learn how to build a simple generic structure representing a 2D vector.

```rust
pub struct Vector<T> {
  x: T,
  y: T,
}
```

Now, obviously, I want to make new vectors: a vector from given coordinates, the null vector and, why not, even an unit vector.

```rust
impl<T: Default + From<u8>> Vector<T> {
  pub fn new(x: T, y: T) -> Self {
    Self { x, y }
  }

  pub fn zero() -> Self {
    Self { x: T::default(), y: T::default() }
  }

  pub fn unit() -> Self {
    Self { x: T::from(1), y: T::from(1) }
  }
}
```

Let's try this out.

```rust
fn main() {
  let v1 = Vector<u8>::new(1, 2);
  let v2 = Vector<u8>::unit();
}
```

This works like a charm. However, let's go from `u8` to `i8`

```rust
 fn main() {
    let v1 = Vector::<i8>::new(1, 2);
    let v2 = Vector::<i8>::unit();
}
```

and then we get the following compilation error

> trait bound `i8: From<u8>` was not satisfied

What can I do from here to be able to use any numeric type?

I know it is possible to use, say, the `FromPrimitive` trait from the `num` crate. Nonetheless, I am still in the learning phase of rust and I want to learn how, if it is possible, to make this with std only.

So, let's start implementing `From<u8>` for `i8`.

```rust
impl From<u8> for i8 {
    fn from(value: u8) -> Self {
        value as Self
    }
}
```

Well, it does not turn well:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for primitive types
  --> main.rs:17:1
   |
1  | impl From<u8> for i8 {
   | ^^^^^--------^^^^^--
   | |    |            |
   | |    |            `i8` is not defined in the current crate
   | |    `u8` is not defined in the current crate
   | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
   |
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

So, let's use macros?

```rust
macro_rules! impl_fromu8 {
    ($($t:ty)*) => {
        $(
            impl From<u8> for $t {
                fn from(value: u8) -> Self {
                    value as Self
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}

impl_fromu8!(i8);
```

Obviously, this is the same code so, it does not work.

For now the only simple possibility I have found is to create a new type just like the compiler told me. Is there another way?

Comment: Due to orphan rule,  we can either implement external traits on local types or implement local traits on external types (and obviously local traits on local types).

Comment: I would suggest moving the `T` bounds to the appropriate method. There is no reason for `Vector::new` to have any bounds, for example. The way you've written the bounds unnecessarily limits what associated functions can be called.

Comment: @cdhowie Can you elaborate what should I do then? Because I checked some libraries and they, mostly, all do it (see this line in the [euclid library](https://github.com/servo/euclid/blob/e43e38a6e94a52005095815023cc310181198152/src/vector.rs#L171) for reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `From<u8>` isn't implemented for `i8`, `TryInto<u8>` is. It might be because the conversion can fail. In this case, however, we know that it cannot, so we can just use unwrap.

This compiles:

```rust
#[allow(dead_code)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Vector<T> {
  x: T,
  y: T,
}

impl<T: Default + TryFrom<u8>> Vector<T> {
  pub fn new(x: T, y: T) -> Self {
    Self { x, y }
  }

  pub fn zero() -> Self {
    Self { x: T::default(), y: T::default() }
  }

  pub fn unit() -> Self where <T as TryFrom<u8>>::Error: core::fmt::Debug {
    Self { x: T::try_from(1).unwrap(), y: T::try_from(1).unwrap() }
  }
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = Vector::<i8>::new(1, 2);
    let v2 = Vector::<i8>::unit();
    
    println!("v1 = {:?}, v2 = {:?}", v1, v2);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that now this type can be used with types that _can_ fail the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [`num-traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits), that define the [`Zero`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/identities/trait.Zero.html) and [`One`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/identities/trait.One.html) trait for cases like this.